# What is the difference between "As" and "Because" in this context?

Tags: differences

> __________ these crops can thrive with so little water, that bodes well for African farmers.

According to the answer key, the only possible word that can finish the gap is **As**. However, why doesn't **Because** work as well - don't they have the same meaning in this case?

I was wondering if we can start a sentence with the latter, but after I did some [research](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-you-start-a-sentence-with-because), I found out it is perfectly fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "Because" is possible, as is "since" or even the informal "seeing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "As" and "Because" are options here. "As" might sound a little better, and some believe starting a sentencing with "Because" is not the best, but again, both are okay to be used in this scenario.